# adding button onto a view programatically

Tags: android, button

If I want to add a button in this class so that I can call the `onclicklistener`, how should I do it?i have also provided the activity class onto which i am adding this view.

activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import android.content.Context;



public class NewGame extends Activity {

View view;
Context context;
RelativeLayout layout;
GameView gameview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gameview=new GameView(this);
    setContentView(gameview);
    //layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);



    //layout.addView(gameview);

}


}
```

view:
    public class GameView extends View {
        Path circle;
        Paint cPaint;
        Paint tPaint;
        String z;
        int i = 65, strt, arc, leftx, topy, rightx, bottomy, maxx, maxy;
        boolean flag1, flag2, flag3;
        double n1, n2;
        int n, n3 = 180,n4,n5 = 90;
        float f1 = 180, f2 = 90;
        Button b1;
        Random r = new Random();
        RectF  oval;

```
    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        leftx = 0;
        topy = 60;
        rightx = 150;
        bottomy = 120;

        z = String.valueOf(Character.toChars(i));

        cPaint = new Paint();
        cPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

        strt = 45;
        arc = 315;

        n1 = Math.random() * 600;
        Log.d("random", z);

        if (flag2 == false)
            new DrawThread(this);

        // cPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        tPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        tPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
        tPaint.setTextSize(20 * scale);
    }

    public void onSizeChanged(int w,int h,int oldh,int oldw) {
        maxx = oldw;
        maxy = oldh;
    }

    //@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Drawing commands go here
        oval = new RectF(leftx,topy,rightx,bottomy);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, strt, arc, true, cPaint);
        while (i < 90)  {
            canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(Character.toChars(i)),f1,f2, tPaint);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Button bt = new Button(this);
bt.setText("A Button");
bt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linerLayout.addView(bt);
```

And then you can do this

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

//TO DO
}
```

I hope that this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

first of all in order to allow to your custom view to have an addView(View v) method it must extend ViewGroup instead of View; then you can use this code

```
b1=new Button(context);
b1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        this.addView(b1);
```

Comment: after doing what you mentioned above i am now getting a blank screen.what do you think can be the problem ?

Comment: try to set an id for the button  b1.setId(1234)

Comment: still getting a blank screen

Comment: try adding text with b1.setText("your text") and using LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT instead of LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT. what if you don't put in your custom view the code for the button?  how are you adding your custom view to the layout? in xml or by code?

Comment: sir i have also provided the activity class above.

Comment: @user2586942 why not use a button in layout. its easier and you can place it where you want.

Comment: @Raghunandan sir but how should i add that button onto this view?

Comment: if your custom view is designed correctly, putting it in a layout using its full package name(like this <your.package.name.GameActivity ) you should see in the designer the result. what do you see if you try to do this?

Comment: I've just seen that you are not providing layout params to your GameView. Try to put in its costructor this.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

Comment: @SimonVeloper now it is giving an exception

Comment: what is giving exception?

Comment: @SimonVeloper  if i use this<your.package.name.GameActivity in the layout and then start the app then on clicking the new game button  it shows a message "the app has to close"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33701/discussion-between-simonveloper-and-user2586942)

Comment: @SimonVeloper and on adding this.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); i am still getting a blank screen

Comment: @SimonVeloper sir i suppose i am not yet elligible for chatting on this site.

Comment: @user2586942 I've moved the conversation in a private chat because is a good practive to avoid extend discussions in comments

Comment: @SimonVeloper yes sir and i tried sending messages to you through private chat.but somehow those messages are not being sent

Comment: have you seen mine messages?

Comment: @SimonVeloper yes sir i have seen your messages.and yes the custom view is rendered in the designer

Comment: @SimonVeloper no sir.and following are the exceptions i am getting

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawArc(Canvas.java:921)
    at org.example.pacman.GameView.onDraw(GameView.java:118)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)

Comment: at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)

Comment: what happens if you comment onDraw overriding?

Comment: and what's the instruction where the nullPointerException is thown?

Comment: @SimonVeloper again alot of exceptions are coming on making the ondraw method a comment

Comment: @SimonVeloper sir whatever i have mentioned above is all that is coming

Comment: ok, maybe I have understood. Live the declaration inside the xml, and put all the code in the constructor in another constructor with this signature  public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)

Comment: I've just tried it, I've put in the constructor this.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));  then I've put the GameView inside a RelativeLayout in a xml file using the last constructor I've suggested ant it works

Comment: @SimonVeloper thanks a lot. sir it is working now.i just wanted to ask you one more thing.sir how do i find the width and height of the screen for this view?

Comment: you can override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) , after calling super.onMeasure you can get height and width by using this.getMeasuredHeight and this.getMeasuredWidth